# Error : <nativehr>0x80131904</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>] Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.DeleteWorkflowAssociation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

In SharePoint 2010 I am trying to remove a workflow association from a list.

When I go to Workflow Settings -> Remove a Workflow -> Remove -> Click OK I get the following error:

```
[COMException (0x80131904): <nativehr>0x80131904</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.DeleteWorkflowAssociation(String bstrUrl, Guid associationId) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteWorkflowAssociation(String bstrUrl, Guid associationId) +149
```

This happens with all workflows associated with the list.

Is this a bug or is there a fix/workaround?

Comment: are you geting any correlation id? any workflow instance is running on the list? is their any lookup type column in the list?

Comment: No lookup column on the list.  The correlation id does not appear in the error page.  There are no workflow instances currently running.

Comment: could you please check the uls logs during that time frame if we can get some clue....a simple trick is close all browser on PC and then try it or even after IIS reset on server.